# Why a link is not correct? (Pyrogram)

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I have to join chats via links, which are in a file.Only 30 links were correct but if i try to join myself it will be succeed.

Last time i tried to use a link in join_chat method:

```
async def main():
    await app.start()
    me = await app.get_me()
    spic = [el.strip() for el in open('links.txt')]
    for el in spic:
        try:
            chat = await app.get_chat(el)
            if me.id not in chat.members:  
                await app.join_chat(el.rstrip())
                await app.archive_chats(chat.id)
            else:
                print("Already in the group:", chat.title)
        except:
            print('Chat is not found')
        await asyncio.sleep(1,5)
```

I also tried to indicate an username received from the link:

```
async def main():
    await app.start()
    spic = [el for el in open('links.txt')]
    for el in spic:
        try:
            username = el.split("/")[-1]
            await app.join_chat(str(username))
            chat = await app.get_chat(username)
            edit_text_file(str(chat.id))
            await app.archive_chats(chat.id)
        except:
            print('Chat is not found')
        await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
```

If i remove except handler i will get this error: "pyrogram.errors.exceptions.bad_request_400.UsernameInvalid: Telegram says: [400 USERNAME_INVALID] - The username is invalid (caused by "contacts.ResolveUsername")"
Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: As a general note, you should nearly never use a plain `except` without defining what could go wrong or logging what actually went wrong. I think you need to provide more information, have you checked the failing username manually?

Comment: even if you want to catch all exceptions, you probably want to catch all `Exception` not all `BaseException`. But I doubt this is the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

The error you’re getting for your second snippet indicates that the `join_chat()` call succeeds, but the `get_chat()` call fails. It fails because `el.split("/")` is not necessarily a valid argument to `get_chat()`.

Also, according to the [documentation for `get_chat()`](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/get_chat), it only accepts invite links of groups that you have previously joined.

If you want to simply join a chat and then archive it, then you can just use the ID of the [`Chat` type](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/Chat) returned from the `join_chat()` call.

Also, note that `[el for el in open("links.txt")]` could contain empty items and hence make failing calls to the Telegram API.

Here’s an improved version of your code that should work:

```py
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait, RPCError

async def main():
    await app.start()
    spic = [el.strip() for el in open("links.txt")]
    chat_ids = []

    for el in spic:
        if not el: # Skip empty lines.
            continue

        try:
            if len(chat_ids) == 20: # Archive 20 chats at once to make less calls.
                await app.archive_chats(chat_id)
                chat_ids = []
        except RPCError as e:
            print("Failed to archive chats:", e)

        try:
            chat = await app.join_chat(el)
        except FloodWait as e:
            await asyncio.sleep(e.value)
        except RPCError as e:
            print("Failed to join chat:", e)

        edit_text_file(str(chat.id))
        chat_ids.append(chat.id)

        await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
    
    if len(chat_ids) > 0:
        await app.archive_chats(chat_ids)
```